# Code not executing after promise is resolved via async/await in React component

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I have the following onSubmit function that gets called when I submit a form. I am rendering `this.state.message` in my render method.

```
  onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    this.setState({ message: 'Waiting on transaction...' })
    try{
      await lottery.methods.enter().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether')
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("ERR!", err)
    }
    this.setState({ message: 'Success!' })
  }
```

When I click on the button, the message "Waiting on transaction" shows up, but after the transaction is complete, the message is not updated to "Success!". I tried wrapping the promise in a try/catch block but there are no errors.

I tried adding a console.log right before the last line but nothing is getting printed to the console.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: if you log before `this.setState({ message: 'Success!' })` do you see the log?

Comment: @Sagivb.g No, if I console.log right before, it does not output to console. It looks like the function is returning immediately after the promise is resolved..

Comment: What makes you think the promise was resolved?

Comment: @Sagivb.g That's a good point. I was making the assumption that it was resolved because I saw the transaction get posted.

Comment: Now familiar with web3, is this a network request?

Comment: From afar it could really be that the promise is not being resolved. Note that it doesn't contradict that something happens, e.g. `new Promise(res => console.log("Hoho, I'll never resolve"))`

Comment: yeah, web3 is a request to the ethereum blockchain, not a standard network request to a server. i think you're right - it looks like the promise is not getting resolved. i'll look into it some more